# Maximum Xor between Two Arrays | Trie

Tags: global-variables, xor, local-variables, trie

Given two integer vectors A and B, we have to pick one element from each vector such that their **xor is maximum** and we need to return this maximum xor value from the function **int Solution::solve(vector &A, vector &B).**

I found out that the code below is **not passing all the test cases** **when I'm declaring and initializing the head pointer globally** right beneath the class Trienode. Why is that?

### Code

```
class Trienode
{
    public:
        Trienode* left;
        Trienode* right;

        Trienode()
        {
            left=0;
            right=0;
        }
};

// Trienode* head = new Trienode;


int Max_Xor_Pair(Trienode* head, vector<int> B)
{
    int n=B.size();
    int max_xor=INT_MIN;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int pair1 = B[i];
        int pair2 = 0;
        Trienode* curr=head;

        for(int j=31; j>=0; j--)
        {
            int bit = (pair1>>j)&1;

            if(bit)
            {
                if(curr->left)
                    curr=curr->left;
                else
                {
                    curr=curr->right;
                    pair2 += pow(2,j);
                }
                    
            }
            else
            {
                if(curr->right)
                {
                    curr=curr->right;
                    pair2 += pow(2,j);
                }
                else
                    curr=curr->left;
            }

        }

        int curr_xor = pair1 ^ pair2;
        max_xor = max(max_xor, curr_xor);
    }
    
    return max_xor;
}

void Insert(Trienode* head, int num)
{
    Trienode* curr=head;
    for(int i=31; i>=0; i--)
    {
        int x = num;
        int bit= (x>>i)&1;

        if(bit)
        {
            if(!curr->right)
            {
                Trienode* temp = new Trienode;
                curr->right=temp;
            }
            curr=curr->right;            
        }
        else
        {
            if(!curr->left)
            {
                Trienode* temp = new Trienode;
                curr->left=temp;
            }
            curr=curr->left;            
        }
    }
}


int Solution::solve(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B) {

    Trienode* head = new Trienode;

    for(int x:A)
        Insert(head,x);

    return Max_Xor_Pair(head,B);
}
```

### Sample Input

**A :** **[** 15891, 6730, 24371, 15351, 15007, 31102, 24394, 3549, 19630, 12624, 24085, 19955, 18757, 11841, 4967, 7377, 13932, 26309, 16945, 32440, 24627, 11324, 5538, 21539, 16119, 2083, 22930, 16542, 4834, 31116, 4640, 29659, 22705, 9931, 13978, 2307, 31674, 22387, 5022, 28746, 26925, 19073, 6271, 5830, 26778, 15574, 5098, 16513, 23987, 13291, 9162 **]**

**B :** **[** 18637, 22356, 24768, 23656, 15575, 4032, 12053, 27351, 1151, 16942 **]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `head` is a global variable, and you don't have this line in `Solution::solve`:

```
 Trienode* head = new Trienode;
```

...then `head` will retain its value after the first test case has finished, and so the second test case will not start with an empty tree. Each test case will *add* more nodes to the *one* tree. Of course this means that, except for the first test case, the tree rooted by `head` is *not* the intended tree.

To make the version with the global variable work, *reset* it in `Solution::solve`:

```
head->left = head->right = nullptr;
```

BTW, you should also initialise these members with `nullptr` (instead of 0) in your `TrieNode` constructor. This better reflects the *intent*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with this approach:

Code:

```
struct Node {
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

class MaxXorHelper{
  private : Node* root;    
  public :
    MaxXorHelper() {
        root = new Node();
    }

    void addElements(vector<int> &arr) {
        for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
            Node* node = root;
            int val = arr[i];
            for(int j=31; j>=0; j--) {
                int bit = (val >> j) & 1;

                if(bit == 0) {
                    if(!node->left) {
                        node->left = new Node();
                    }
                    node = node->left;
                } 
                else {
                    if(!node->right) {
                        node->right = new Node();
                    }
                    node = node->right;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int findMaxXor(vector<int> &arr) {
        int maxXor = INT_MIN;
        for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
            Node* node = root;
            int val2 = 0;
            int val1 = arr[i];
            for(int j=31; j>=0; j--) {
                int bit = (val1 >> j) & 1;

                if(bit == 0) {
                    if(node->right) {
                        val2 |= (1 << j);
                        node = node->right;
                    } else{
                        node = node->left;
                    } 
                }
                else {
                    if(node->left) {
                        node = node->left;
                    } else{
                        val2 |= (1 << j);
                        node = node->right;
                    }
                }
            }
            int curXor = val1 ^ val2;
            maxXor = max(maxXor, curXor);
        }
        return maxXor;
    }
};

int Solution::solve(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B) {
    MaxXorHelper helper;
    helper.addElements(A);
    return helper.findMaxXor(B);
}
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this approach over the accepted answer? What are the major differences between your approaches? Are there specific scenarios where this might be better suited?